# Create polygon of non-transparent parts of image

Tags: java, arrays, image, polygon

What I am trying to achieve is getting a mask of an `image`, converting it into an `Array` with the dimensions `(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight())`, then getting all the pixels and seeing if they have an alpha value of `0`.

IF they do, then:

- add value `1` for the `x, y` co-ordinate that I am examining at the moment.

ELSE:

- add value `0` for the `x, y` co-ordinate that I am examining at the moment.

Up to this point, I know how to program this. If you are interested, this is the code I am using:

```
private int[] createMask(BufferedImage image) {

    final int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    final int width = image.getWidth();
    final int height = image.getHeight();
    final boolean hasAlphaChannel = image.getAlphaRaster() != null;

    int[][] result = new int[height][width];
    if (hasAlphaChannel) {
        for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += 4) {
            int alpha = pixels[pixel];
            if(alpha != 0) {
                result[row][col] = 1;
            } else {
                result[row][col] = 0;
            }

            if (col == width) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        } 
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

After I get this mask, I am attempting to use this `Array` to draw a `Polygon` via this code, or an alternation of it (obtained from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html) :

```
    int x1Points[] = {0, 100, 0, 100};
    int y1Points[] = {0, 50, 50, 0};
    GeneralPath polygon = 
    new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,
                    x1Points.length);
    polygon.moveTo(x1Points[0], y1Points[0]);

    for (int index = 1; index < x1Points.length; index++) {
        polygon.lineTo(x1Points[index], y1Points[index]);
    };

    polygon.closePath();
    g2.draw(polygon);
```

However, I need to create a method which gives me all the co-ordinates in an `Array` consisting of `Point` objects to go around the image to essentially create a "mask".

```
    public Point[] getCords(int[] mask) {
        ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(); //you can change this to whatever you want to use

        //get coords to surround the mask
        // >> involving `0` (for transparent) and `1` (non transparent) 
        //  >> these are contained in the `mask` Array...

        return points.toArray(new Points[0]);
```

---

So, to conclude:

- I require to obtain a polygon that outlines an image's visible pixels from an `int[]` array which contains the values `1`'s and `0`'s, the former for non-transparent pixel and latter for transparent pixel, respectively.

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading because you state twice "what you're trying to achieve" and those two instances tell about different goals (one you got working, the other is the actual problem).

Comment: @Suseika  sorry, that is in fact the incorrect wording. I'm just stating what I already have.

Comment: It's fine, just edit your question so someone with a similar problem can appreciate your question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(link to related java code below)

To create the mask border, do the following: for each pair of coordinates (x,y) check if any one of 8 its neighboring points is outside the mask. However, keep in mind that the resulting mask isn't necessarily 1 pixel wide and vectorizing it might be non-trivial, as in this example (white is the masked area, red is the mask border inside the mask, black is unmasked area):

[image: Mask border in red]

Luckily, even if you get a wider-than-1-pixel border in some places in your mask, you can workaround that by rejecting some pixels of the mask from that mask building a submask that is polygonizable. The following image shows the submask's border in blue:

[image: Submask border in blue]

I implemented such algorithm a while ago. There is the code you can use, but it is quite tightly coupled with my solution, however you could find some insights in it: [Thick mask border resolution](https://github.com/Suseika/tendiwa-backend/blob/f437ed0a7eeec3d9eabf7637f9e876e31b86e079/src/main/java/org/tendiwa/settlements/cityBounds/KnotResolvingCells.java). Its idea is that from the initial mask you build a submask by flood-filling original mask with a predicate that checks that a cell of submask's border has at most 2 cardinal direction neighbors (ordinal direction neighbors don't matter here).

Once you got the blue submask's border, build a graph where vertices are points of submask's border, and edges are between cardinally neighboring points. Then traverse each component of that graph, and for each component you get a list of points that form your polygons.

Comment: Looks exactly like what I want! Awesome! Will look at in detail when I'm at my pc!